# Floating point exception (core dumped) ao executar trainhog.cpp do OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Olá,
Estou desenvolvendo uma solução para detecção de objetos em uma imagem, utilizando HOG+SVM. Até então apenas montei meu banco de dados de amostras positivas e negativas.

Fui utilizar o código de exemplo do OpenCV trainghog.cpp, apenas inseri os meus parâmetros como está abaixo:

```
const char* keys =
    {
        "{help h|     | show help message}"
        "{pd    |../../amostras/positivas| path of directory contains possitive images}"
        "{nd    |../../amostras/negativas| path of directory contains negative images}"
        "{td    |../../testes| path of directory contains test images}"
        "{tv    |     | test video file name}"
        "{dw    |64| width of the detector}"
        "{dh    |64| height of the detector}"
        "{d     |false| train twice}"
        "{t     |false| test a trained detector}"
        "{v     |true| visualize training steps}"
        "{fn    || file name of trained SVM}"
    };
```

Não mudei nenhuma outra linha do código. As imagens positivas são lidas, quando chega a vez das negativas, aparece isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o que pode ser este erro?

Como sugerido, aqui está o link que contém o codigo de exemplo: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/train_HOG.cpp

Comment: Creio que com o código ajudaria os outros usuários a compreender o problema.

Comment: O código tem umas 400 linhas e vem junto ao instalar o opencv, por isso não postei aqui, ía ficar muito grande, mas se achar relevante eu posto

Comment: Seria [este código](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/train_HOG.cpp)? Edite a pergunta com o link. Ou veja [este](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sturkmen72/opencv/403682ff600098cebfdd1e3a4f51313342f1ad15/samples/cpp/train_HOG.cpp)

Comment: Tente trocar de `CV_32FC1` para `CV_32SC1` por causa [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33602246/7690982). Seu erro está nesta parte do código:     `clog << "Negative images are being loaded...";
    load_images( neg_dir, full_neg_lst, false );
    sample_neg( full_neg_lst, neg_lst, pos_image_size );
    clog << "...[done]" << endl;`

Comment: Sim, é o código de "este código". Vou tentar as  alterações que sugeriu, obrigado! Qualquer coisa comento aqui de novo!

Comment: Fiz a alteração de CV_32FC1 para CV_32SC1 como sugeriu, porém continuo obtendo o mesmo erro. Acredito que o problema esteja na  função sample_neg, pois troquei o false de load_images para visualize e elas foram carregadas. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Esse erro ocorre quando há alguma operação inválida, divisão por zero, overflow, underflow ou inexata. Creio que seja algo do tamanho das imagens, qual a resolução das imagens em pd e em nd?

Comment: São de 64 x 64 pixels

Comment: Estranho, provavelmente `( full_neg_lst[i].rows - size_y )` ou `( full_neg_lst[i].cols - size_x )` está dando zero. Tente mudar o tamanho das imagens, ou um teste somando 1 nestas linhas. Mas se isso estiver ocorrendo, sugiro abrir uma [Issue no Github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Desculpe a demora, com o tempo eu acabei esquecendo do HOG. Vou abrir uma issue no github mesmo, recente fui mexer no HOG de novo e não consegui solucionar este problema